# Is it possible to solve this PDE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

It would be pretty sweet if I could solve this for $A$.  Is it possible?

$$\frac{dA}{dx}+\frac{dA}{d\tau}=wx\tau$$

where $w$ is a constant and $x$ is a function of $\tau$.

It might help that it is also known that:

$$w\tau=\frac{d^2A}{dx^2}$$

So the equation to be solved could also be expressed:

$$\frac{dA}{dx}+\frac{dA}{d\tau}=\frac{d^2A}{dx^2}x$$

Comment: How about if we differentiate your first equation w.r.t $x$ and w.r.t $\tau$ and then substract. This gives us $\frac{\partial ^2 A}{\partial x^2} -\frac{\partial ^2 A}{\partial \tau^2} =w(x-\tau)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, it's a PDE (partial differential equation), not an ODE.

Let $B = A + w x^3/6 - w x^2 \tau/2$.  Then your first equation becomes
$$ \dfrac{\partial B}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial B}{\partial \tau} = 0$$ which
is equivalent (apart from quibbles about differentiability) to 
$B = F(x - \tau)$.  Then $\dfrac{\partial^2 A}{\partial x^2} = F''(x-\tau) + w(x - \tau)$.  Now the bad news: that can't be $w \tau$, it must be a function of $x - \tau$.

Comment: Cool. How did you think of your choice of function $B$? It seems that often in these kinds of problems it is about intuitively finding a solution that might work and then just checking it.

Comment: I admit that I cheated: I used Maple.